# Python Raspery pi serial get stuck on Write

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, serial-port, uart

I wanted to start serial on my RasperyPi Model B but i notice that it get stuck on 
Serial.Write("ETC")

The python module I am Using is [PySerial](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial)

This is the code I have tried:

```
import serial
import time
test=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",9600)
time.sleep(1)
print('1')
test.write("SomeStuff".encode("ascii"))
print('2')
```

It stuck on write() and wont show '2'

I am also getting the same issue in these snippets:

```
test.open() : #Its already open
test.write(bytes('Em','ascii')) #Not working / Same
test.write('hi?'.encode()) #Same !
```

-

```
 test=serial.Serial()
 test.baudrate=9600
 test.timeout=0
 test.port="/dev/ttyAMA0"

 test.open()
 test.write('hi?'.encode())
```

-

```
 test=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",115200) #Even more baudrates..
```

Why does this code get stuck on write and how can I fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using  `test=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0",115200) #Even more baudrates..`
will be better ! it works fine now